# neo4j - labels vs properties vs relationship + node

Tags: modeling, node-neo4j, neo4j

Any rule of thumb on where to use label vs node property vs relationship + node.

Let's have an example, say I have a store and I want to put my products in neo4j.  Their identifier is the product sku, and I also want to have a categorization on them like this one is for clothes, food, electronics, and you get the idea.  I'll be having a free search on my graph, like the user can search anything, and I'd return all the things related to that search string.

Would it be better to use:

1. I have a node with `sku 001`, and I'll tag it a label of `Food`.
2. I have a node with `sku 001`, and have property on this node called `category:"Food"`
3. I have a node with `sku 001`, and I'll create another node for the `Food`, and will create a relationship of "`category`" to relate them.

I have read that if you'll be looking up a property, it's better off as a relationship + node, as traversing is much faster than looking up properties of node.

TIA

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Whether you should use a property, a label or a node for the category depends on how you will be querying the data.

(I'll assume here that you have a fairly small, fairly fixed set of categories.)

*Use a property* if you won't be querying by category, but just need to return the category of a node that has been found by other means. (For example: what is the category of the item with `sku 001`?)

*Use a label* if you need to query by category. (For example: what are all the foods costing less than $10?)

*Use a node* if you need to traverse the category without knowing what it is. (For example: what are the ten most popular items in the same category as one that the user has chosen?)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the third option is most *robust* in the sense that you could easily accomplish all 3 goals with such a structure with lowest hit on performance as opposed to the other 2 methods? I'm imagining a structure for this question similar to: **1** `(:user)-[LIKES]->(:node:food {sku: 1, cost: 10})`, **2** `(:user)-[LIKES]->(:node {sku: 1, category: "food", cost: 10})`, and **3** `(:user)-[LIKES]->(:node {sku: 1, cost: 10})-[HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Category {name: "food"})` where option 3 allows for easiest querying of all 3 of your examples.

Answer (score 16):

[This blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-genericvague-relationship-names/) may also be helpful because of the benchmark it contains.

> I modelled the ‘relationship’ in 4 different ways…
>
> - Using a specific relationship type `(node)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(address)`
> - Using a generic relationship type and then filtering by end node    label `(node)-[:HAS]->(address:Address)`
> - Using a generic relationship type and then filtering by relationship property `(node)-[:HAS {type:“address”}]->(address)`
> - Using a generic relationship type and then filtering by end node    property `(node)-[:HAS]->(address {type: “address”})`
>
> <...>
>
> So in summary…specific relationships #ftw!

Comment: The benchmarks give a very good pointer - but they show that using specific relationships is faster than generic ones. They decision to using property vs label vs node is still contingent on the queries themselves.